# How to pass data between two ViewControllers without using segues and NaviagationController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

My problem it's when instance a SecondViewController in FirstViewController for assign a value on variable ID, the problem is I can not use Segue and NaviagtioController..
Maybe a solution use a Static variable?, How do it, or tell me a tip?

I do it this code:

```
// In the class FirstViewController.m
#import "SecondViewController"

NSString *identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.cat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
// Start the code causes an error
ViewControllerOne *instance = [[ViewControllerOne alloc]init];
instance.ID = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",identifier];
// End code causes error

// In the SecondViewController.h    
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *ID;

// In the SecondViewController.m
@synthesize ID;
```

The debug error:

> 2013-05-03 09:01:42.126 TheFreeApp[19880:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1cbc012 0x10f9e7e 0x1cbbdeb 0x53d748 0x558b1b 0x558646 0x11eff8 0x11f232 0x5588d5 0xbf5b 0x11ce1e 0xb74e 0xed285 0xed4ed 0xaf75b3 0x1c7b376 0x1c7ae06 0x1c62a82 0x1c61f44 0x1c61e1b 0x1c167e3 0x1c16668 0x3dffc 0x2bcd 0x2af5)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>   (lldb)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:yourVal forKey:@"myValue"];
NSString *myVal = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"myValue"];
```

Hope i helped

Answer (score 3):

Cause of error is very clear from the log **Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'UICollectionView must be initialized with a non-nil layout parameter'**

Your `ViewControllerOne` is a `UICollectionViewController` sub class. It should be initialize with a non nil layout parameter.

```
 UICollectionViewLayout *layout= [UICollectionViewFlowLayout new];
 ViewControllerOne *instance = [[ViewControllerOne alloc]initWithCollectionViewLayout:layout];
```

However passing data between view controller remains there.

Comment: I strongly doubt, did you mean `SecondViewController` in place of `ViewControllerOne`?? How you are going from firstVC to secondVC??